# Correlated or biased coin protocols?

Tags: protocol-design, reference-request, literature

There are a number of papers in the literature describing secure/fair coin flipping protocols. Unfortunately in my case, I am looking for coins that are epsilon-biased or epsilon-correlated. I am looking for a coin-flipping protocol that is guaranteed to output correlated and/or biased coins to parties for some pre-agreed levels of correlation or biasing or fail securely.

Comment: Should it reveal all of the coins to every party? $\;$

Comment: My guess is that it should be easy to turn one into the other using other cryptographic tools, but I'm interested in either case.

Comment: I suspect that in the two-party case, giving them distinct but "interestingly"-correlated $\hspace{.95 in}$ random outputs should be sufficient for oblivious transfer. $\:$